# max-width media query takes wrong width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I have a queries.css that currently takes in

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1140px){
  .row,
  .hero-img{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 930px){
  /* code */ 
}
```

But when the browser(chrome) is at width of 1023, it registers the code for the max-width:930px media query.

Does anyone know what the issue is here. I saw other posts related and they had said to use min-width and the meta tag, both of which I did and still causes the same problem .

Also when I try to write code into my 1140px max-width media query, the media query for 930px overrides that one.

Comment: you have something else at play because this should work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ubkftv9u/

Comment: Can you post the actual code, not the abbreviated version? Or reproduce your issue in a snippet or on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 100%){
  .row,
  .hero-img{
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 100%){
  /* code */ 
}
```